# Can I have a better solution to raise the PropertyChanged in Communitytoolkit ObservableCollection, this is a MAUI framwork

Tags: maui

I'm using MVVM pattern, communitytoolkit library, sqlite database, and entityframework core, When I edit an entity, then go back to list(collectionview), the collectionview doesn't reflect changes.
this is viewmodel code,

```
   public partial class TeamsViewModel : ObservableObject {
            public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams {
                get;set;}

        private readonly IViewTeamsUseCase _viewTeamsUseCase;
        private readonly IDeleteTeamUseCase _deleteTeamUseCase;

        public TeamsViewModel(IViewTeamsUseCase viewTeamsUseCase, IDeleteTeamUseCase deleteTeamUseCase) {
       
            Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
            _viewTeamsUseCase = viewTeamsUseCase;
            _deleteTeamUseCase = deleteTeamUseCase;
        }
                 LoadTeamsMethod(filterText); 
            }
        }

        private async void LoadTeamsMethod(string filterText) {
            await LoadTeamsAsync(filterText);
        }
        public async Task LoadTeamsAsync(string filterText = null) {
            
            Teams.Clear();
            var teams = await _viewTeamsUseCase.ExecuteAsync(filterText);
            if (teams != null && teams.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var team in teams) {
                    this.Teams.Add(team);
                }
            }
        }
```

this is view page code,

```
  public TeamsPage(TeamsViewModel teamsViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _teamsViewModel = teamsViewModel;
            this.BindingContext = _teamsViewModel;
        }
        protected override async void OnAppearing() {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await _teamsViewModel.LoadTeamsAsync();
        }
```

The problem code is at repository,

```
   public async Task UpdateTeam(int teamId, Team team)
    {
        var teamToUpdate = await _context.Teams.FindAsync(teamId);
        if (teamToUpdate is not null)
        {
            teamToUpdate.Name = team.Name;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

**if I change updateTeam code to below code, it's working perfectly.**

```
    public async Task UpdateTeam(int teamId, Team team) {
        if (teamId != team.TeamId) { return; }
        var teamToUpdate = await _context.Teams.FindAsync(teamId);
        if (teamToUpdate is not null) {
            _context.Teams.Remove(teamToUpdate);
            _context.Add(new Team { Name = team.Name });
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

I also tried a decorate to Teams collection,

public partial class TeamsViewModel : ObservableObject {

```
private ObservableCollection<Team> _teams;
public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams {
    get;set;
   get => _teams;
   set { 
    SetProperty(ref _teams, value);            
}
```

When I debug those code block,

```
            Teams.Clear();
        var teams = await _viewTeamsUseCase.ExecuteAsync(filterText);
        if (teams != null && teams.Count > 0) {
            teams= teams.OrderBy(team => team.Name).ToList();
            foreach (var team in teams) {
                this.Teams.Add(team);
            }
        }
```

Before  Teams.Clear(), **Teams data already updated.**

My understanding is Teams is an observablecollection, it will be monitored by collectionview, but if I use EFcore, it seems observablecollection Teams is tracked and updated at realtime, even I do Teams.Clear(); it doesn't work, The framework can not detect changes in Teams. So I have remove that entity, then add a new entity, the system can detect changes, and raise a PropertyChanged event.

Is my understanding right? Can anybody give me a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: ObservableCollection only updates when you add/remove items from the collection.  To update when changes are made to properties of an item in the collection, those properties need to be Observable.

Comment: If you made Team observable as well you wouldn't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

From document [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0), we could know:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
> items get added or removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

And if you want UI update automatically while modifying the value of property
for the Item of data list, you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your item model and call method `OnPropertyChanged` for the properties you want to modify.

For example:

```
public class Team: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {   
        // modify Name property as follows          
        private bool _name;
        public bool Name 
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _name, value);
            }
            get { return _name; }
        }
     

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Of course, if you also use nuget [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features) to achieve this, which can simply above code.

```
public partial class Team:ObservableObject
{  
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool name;
}
```

**Note:**

For more information, please check document: [Introduction to the MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) and [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).

Comment: Hi Jessie, Thank for your reply, I also tried below code,     public partial class TeamsViewModel : ObservableObject {

        private ObservableCollection<Team> _teams;
        public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams {
            get;set;
            get => _teams;
            set { 
            SetProperty(ref _teams, value); But still doesn't work, When I debug below code block,            
            Teams.Clear();
            var teams = await _viewTeamsUseCase.ExecuteAsync(filterText);
            if (teams != null && teams.Count > 0) {

Comment: Do you want UI to refresh itself while changing the value of some properties of the `Teams`, right? Then please add `ObservableProperty` for the properties of `Team.cs`.

Comment: `Before Teams.Clear(), Teams data already updated. `  And then where did the problem go arise? Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Hi Jessie,  Teams data used in UI,  <CollectionView 
  x:Name="TeamsCollection"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"
  Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="0">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Team">

Comment: USE CASE LIKE screen display a list of team, then I click a team item, it will go to edit team page, I edit team data, then click save button, it will go back to teams page, which will call  public async Task LoadTeamsAsync(string filterText = null) {
      Teams.Clear();
      var teams = await _viewTeamsUseCase.ExecuteAsync(filterText);
      if (teams != null && teams.Count > 0) {
          foreach (var team in teams) {
              this.Teams.Add(team);
      }  before call this method, teams data should be not edited, but when I debug it, teams data already been updated,

Comment: I recon the system compare UI teams data befor and after LoadTeamsAsync method, it cannot detect any changes, so can not raise a propertychanged event.

Comment: `before call this method, teams data should be not edited, but when I debug it, teams data already been updated`  I  cannot see other code of your app. But you can first recheck if you have added some code on method `OnAppearing`  or `OnNavigatedTo`  of  `YourPage.xaml`  to load data.

Comment: You can also refer to the official sample here : [NET MAUI - Local Database with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/database-sqlite/).

Comment: Hi Jessie, I do have load data OnAppearing,       protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
       await _studentsViewModelcs.LoadTeamsAsync();
    }

Comment: After you save the edited data, do you reload the data in `OnAppearing()`?

Comment: Hi Jessie, Yes, I reload the data in OnAppearing(), and I also debugged it, the data is updated, but when it displayed on screen, it did not updated, if I edit it again, the data is already edited.

Comment: Hi Jessie, this is OnAppearing method in Teams list page,     protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SearchBar.Text = string.Empty;
        await _teamsViewModel.LoadTeamsAsync();
    }

Comment: and below is loadteamsasync method in viewmodel.           public async Task LoadTeamsAsync(string filterText = null) {            
            Teams.Clear();
            var teams = await _viewTeamsUseCase.ExecuteAsync(filterText);
           teams = teams.OrderBy(team => team.Name).ToList();
            if (teams != null && teams.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var team in teams) {
                    this.Teams.Add(team);}}}

Comment: Sorry, from the code you shared, I didn't see exactly what the problem was. But could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: Sorry, after I downloaded your demo and tried to deploy it to my emulator, the app crashed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Both TeamsViewModel and Teams should be observable. Since you're using the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` you should make use of **BOTH** `ObservableObject` and `ObservableProperty`. The latter being a source generator so you don't have to write the boiler-plate code:

```cs
// TeamsViewModel.cs
public partial class TeamsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Team> _teams;
}
```

```cs
// Team.cs
public partial class Team: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _teamId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _name;
}
```

By doing so, the parent `ObservableCollection` will give you notification of additions, deletes and updates to the collection, whilst the inner `ObservableObject` will give you notifications of updates to individual `Team` properties.

Note, that I deliberately made all my members private and begin with an underscore (_) lowercase. The `[ObservableProperty]` attribute will instruct the source code generator to create a public version of this as a property with capitalization and camel case as well as fill out the getters and setters.

It's worth checking out James Montemagno's YouTube videos on MVVM Source Generators: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vvm_-YveTs

Comment: Hi Stephen, Do you mean I should create two files for Team class, 1.    public class Team {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }                            2.    public partial class Team : ObservableObject {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _teamId;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _name;
    }                        Is that your point?

Comment: Hi @JoshDing I reread your code, and I suspect your problem is your constructor initializes/changes the value of `Teams` but does not notify it, so, it's missing an `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Teams))` call. So one solution is you need to add the `OnPropertyChanged` call to your constructor. Otherwise, had you used `[ObservableProperty]` like I suggested the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` would have emitted that signal automatically for you. You should really look up `[ObservableProperty]`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, where is Team.cs put in, I mean this class, // Team.cs
public partial class Team: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _teamId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _name;
}                                    In my solution, Team model class is in another project, .

Comment: Sure, if you want the `Team` model class in another project but in the same solution, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: My question is where should I put in, should I put public partial class Team: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _teamId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _name;
}, in view model class, or new a new class for public partial class Team: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _teamId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _name;
}

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused. Team is a class, make it observable so then, it's like a VM. TeamsViewModel is a class, it is also observable, so, it's a VM too. There's nothing wrong with that. As to where you put this class, I'm not telling you anywhere specific, because, it doesn't matter. C# will not care. As long as the namespaces and the using are set up so that they can be found, then, it's all good, right?